# Do gameplay choices in Metro 2033 have an effect on the story in Metro: Last Light?

Tags: metro-2033, metro-last-light

I recently completed Metro 2033 with the alternative ending of saving the dark ones. I started playing Metro: Last Light today but the game is continuing as if I did blow them up. Is this because of the choices I made in 2033?

Comment: The plot of the first game is (roughly) based on the novel by Dmitry Glukhovsky which is the first of a series. While games do sometimes have different endings, novels usually do not. I think that they didn't want the story of the games to differ too much from the story of the books. So the developers decided to follow the ending which is closest to the ending of the novel. A feature to import a savegame from the previous game (like in the Mass Effect series, for example) would have been conceivable, but there weren't enough decisions in the first game to justify this.

Comment: This is easy to answer given the back story, but asking "why they made it this way" dips awfully close to developer intent

Comment: As Timelord has stated, this is effectively asking for developer input, which is off-topic. Try to re-word it so that it's **not** effectively asking "Why did they make it this way?"

Answer (score 5):

Developers will often give the player a choice, which in turn has an impact on what ending you will reach. However, this poses an issue, when making a sequel. Suddenly, their game has several different starting possibilities, often differing greatly in story, and who is alive or dead.

Whilst some games are heavily designed this way (take Mass Effect as a good example), and import your old save, building the story dynamically, many developers do not go this way.

Instead, one ending is considered "canon", and the rest are considered "alternate realities", or simply events that did not actually happen.

As has been stated before, **Metro is based off novels written by Dmitry Glukhovsky. In the novel, the dark ones are blown up, at the end. So naturally, this is the canon ending.** in order to allow the canon story to persist into the second game.

Comment: +1 for the "canon ending" explanation. This effectively means that the alternate ending is just that; an *alternate* ending. Or and "easter egg ending" if you will.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. You can't import a save into Last Light, and the game assumes that the "bad" ending of the first game is canon. As Phillip noted, they're based on a novel series by an author (who returned to write Last Light).